# `FirebaseInstallations` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.12.0`, Build failed: Your project requires a newer version of CocoaPods

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, react-native, eas

In my react native project, when I run `eas build --platform ios` I get this error below

```
[!] `FirebaseInstallations` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.12.0`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.11.3`.

Build failed: Your project requires a newer version of CocoaPods. You can update it in the build profile in eas.json by either:
- changing the current version under key "cocoapods"
- switching to an image that supports that version under key "image"
```

I have run `sudo gem install cocoapods` and `pod --version` says `1.15.2`

also run `Cd ios`, `pod deintegrate`, `npx pod-install`

I have also updated my `eas.json`

```
"ios": {
       "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
       "cocoapods": "1.15.2"
     }
```

But I'm still getting the same error when building for IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to add `"cocoapods": "1.15.2"` under `build.production` and I only had it under `build.development` so for it to work, it should look something like this:

```
 "build": {
 "production": {
      "ios": {
        "cocoapods": "1.15.2"
      },
      "channel": "production"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Run `brew upgrade cocoapods` command.

If that doesn't work try `brew install cocoapods`

Comment: Doesn't work, same error, @RashmiRekha

Comment: Run  `brew cleanup -d -v`  command and then run  `brew install cocoapods`. Try this way